# Oracle Apex return specific values from PL/SQL into a item

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm using apex 4.0 and I've currently got a SQL query that looks up a table information with SUM and includes simple math with a case statement that display OK if it tallies up or NOT okay if it doesn't in a separate row,

In apex if I use PL/SQL can I return the values specific values specifically the OK to an ITEM in apex to be used elsewhere? I've searched and cannot find anything exact likely because I'm currently ensure on the correct term.

[image: Example of table]

Answer (score 4):

If you have a page item called P123_FOO then you can do this in a page process:

```
select <whatever>
  into :P123_FOO
  from <whatever>;
```

The usual exceptions will be raised if the query returns no rows or more than one.

Comment: Thanks Tony Andrews.